# How to change order of divs in HTML code, for 3-column CSS Layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, seo

I found a good CSS code that makes a 3-column layout, from [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/basic-3-column-fixed-width-css-layout/). But the problem is, HTML code must be in this order :

```
<div class='left'></div>
<div class='right'></div>
<div class='content'></div>
```

and for SEO purposes, I want to put content first. But it breaks the layout. Please see [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/).

So how can I make it work with all orderings? Or just the one (2-1-3) ordering ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/2/

Comment: Thank you @DaggNabbit, this version is very close to the answer. But the columns do not stretch in height. See: http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/12/

Comment: I know, that's why it's not an answer ;)

Comment: What you are looking for is discussed at: http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

Comment: @MarcAudet this seems to be my answer. Please let me test. And you may post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;` (don't forget to set the container to `position:relative;`):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/11/)**

CSS:

```
.threecolumns_container {
    width: 750px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

.threecolumns_left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.threecolumns_content {

    width:396px;
    position:absolute;
    left:150px;
}

.threecolumns_right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;   
}

.threecolumns_clear {
    clear: both;
}


/* demo : 
----------*/
.threecolumns_container
{
    background-color:rgba(25,2,2,0.1);
}

.threecolumns_left
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.threecolumns_content
{
    border:1px solid green;
}
.threecolumns_right
{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is even closer than DaggNabbit's answer. but still, the absolute positioned elements do not contribute to the overall height of the container. See: http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/13/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : change the css for **.threecolumns_content** :

```
.threecolumns_content {

    float:left;
    width:391px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying that ! But it doesn't work. see : http://jsfiddle.net/RW3Py/1/

Comment: But I want `.content` to be in the middle on the page. It should be on top only in the source code.